# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode in Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am following a tutorial from a book, we have just set up a heroku based mongodb database alongside a local database. The local app works fine but when I run it on Heroku I get the following error

```
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7
const Schema = require('./schema');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

I'm guessing that the fact the version of Node on Heroku is different to my localhost but maybe it is not.

when I do node --version on my local I get

```
v8.9.3
```

when I do it on Heroku I get

```
v0.10.48
```

which is a bit confusing.

How can I fix this so that it runs on Heroku. I have contacted their support but they sent me here as it is an application issue.

Thanks

Comment: Add `'use strict'` as first line of script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#node-js-runtimes). If you want to have a specific version of nodejs, which for example supports `const` use the engines section of your `package.json`.

Sample from Heroku:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is now working. Any info on the jump from 0.10.48 to 8.9.3. Is my book really just that old..? it came out in 2014

Comment: If I remember correctly there was a big jump in version when node and io.js were merged https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/foundation-v4-announce/. Still your book is old :P